# iPhone app not responding until I toggle scale (2x/1x ipad zoom in corner)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

I install my app to my iPad2.
Tab bar controller, nothing fancy.
App won't change tabs until I tap the 1x/2x button in the corner.
When I change zoom the tabs become responsive.
What the hell.. ?

EDIT: added an empty UIButton on the first tab's nib. It won't respond until I change the zoom level.

EDIT: viewDidLoad for both of the tabs just calls super.

EDIT: NSLog statements in viewDidLoad show up.

It's a very fresh project. (<2 hours and I moved my method calls out of viewDidLoad to see if I was doing anything that would cause the freezing).I don't remember this happening before but I often idly play with the zoom levels for fun so it's possible I missed it.

Comment: Restarting my iPad didn't help.

Comment: Resuming from background is fine. Only when first launching.

Comment: What about in the iPad simulator? iOS 5 or 6?

Answer (score 0):

Never seen this particular problem, but any time I've had a strange interaction like that, it has either been forgetting to call super in one of the various view lifecycle methods, or forgetting to assign window.rootViewController.  Since you're not very far into the process, it's probably worth just starting fresh with a new project from the standard template, and see what happens.

Comment: I am explicitly using iPhone nibs in AppDelegate.
If I run it as an iPad app instead of iPhone, the nibs show full screen and the app works. Go figure.

Comment: Removing the non portrait orientations works. I'm going to close the question, no clear problem.